# Excel to Smart Sheets

Tags: smartsheet-api

I am need to convert my Excel sheet into Smartsheet. I tries to upload the document from Excel and Google Sheets but tbe formulas do not transfer. How can I create new formulas in Smartsheet that correspond with the formula in Excel or Google Sheet. How do I determine the new formulas for Smartsheet?

Comment: I'd suggest you post this question to the Smartsheet Community [Using Smartsheet](https://community.smartsheet.com/categories/using-smartsheet) online support forum, as that's the appropriate place for questions like this that seek help with in-app functionality. (Stack Overflow is a venue for programming-related questions -- i.e., if you're having trouble using the Smartsheet API. Based on the information you've provided, it doesn't sound like you're using the API.) If you are, in fact, using the API -- please update your question to show your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you import into smartsheet, you have to select the checkbox to keep formulas from your excel file.

[checkbox to keep formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9yIH.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).